# Any free software for creating paid WIFI?

Tags: wifi

Anyone know free software (or very cheap) for creating paid access to WIFI - with tokens mechanism?
Can be on Linux, or Windows... I have a small Hostel and I want to create paid access to wifi (like 1$ for hour)

Comment: So you want to charge for WiFi but you don't want to pay for the technology that allows you to do that? Hmm...

Comment: @Joe - how is that any different from running a website, that generates money, on a free Linux?

Comment: Probably not any different. It just strikes me as a bit odd that the OP wants to make money from something he wants to get for free. I'm not trying to start an ethics debate but IMHO these two parameters are at odds with each other.

Comment: @joeqwerty: He's paying for equipment as well as internet access. I'd not call that free.

Comment: @Billy: I'm not talking about the supporting infrastructure, I'm talking specifically about the "product" he wants to sell: WiFi access. He wants to charge for a product that he himself wants to get for free. For me that's a conflict. If others have no problem with it, I have no problem with them. This is only my opinion and as such, I probably shouldn't have posted it here. :)

Comment: @joeqwerty: I just don't see how he's getting it for free.

Comment: Here's an analogy: He wants to get fuel for his car for free and then charge people for giving them taxi rides. Sure, he has to pay for the rest of the car but without the fuel he has no "product" to sell (the product being taxi rides in the car).

Answer (score 2):

The [Coova project](http://www.coova.org/) is probably a good starting place. There's a module to [sell access with PayPal](https://om.coova.net/docs/paypal), so presumably you could use that to lay the groundwork for what you wanted to do if it doesn't do what you want "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

DD-WRT supports Chillspot:
 http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot

I believe you need to setup a RADIUS server to make full use of it though.

Comment: CoovaChilli is the currently-maintained fork of the Chillispot code.